# Autosizing boxes and positioning in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, interface, interface-builder, size, positioning

I'm creating an application, from which a part looks like this:

[boo http://img188.imageshack.us/img188/7808/schermafbeelding2010021y.png](http://img188.imageshack.us/img188/7808/schermafbeelding2010021y.png)

I all dragged them to a window in IB, but the problem is that the NSImageView, Action Buttons (Suggest, Send, Poke etc...), Information NSBox, and Friends NSTabView can all vary in height. They should always be placed below each other, with a margin of 8px. Just like on Facebook. I thought of a very modified NSSplitView, but maybe there are easier ways. Can anyone help me out?

Edit: I have placed the action buttons in a Custom View with class NSView.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the image view always be square? And I don't see why the buttons should be resizable, except horizontally. These two constraints relieve the need for users to be able to resize those views, which frees you to use a regular split view, not a custom split view, for the box and tab view.

Comment: The buttons aren't resizable, but there can be more or less then 3 of them, for example, the button 'Suggest Friends for John' is not there if you are logged in as John.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to manually resize the views yourself.  Cocoa does not provide Java-style LayoutManagers.  However, I don't think it would be too hard to recreate one...

Comment: Well, they resize automatically based on their content. The only problem is positioning.

Comment: @Koning that's what I meant (sorry for not being clear).  You'll have to manually alter each view's origin via the `setFrame:` method (which would also allow you to manipulate height/width at the same time).